# AJAX event for when the server receives the request - before processing it

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-events

I'm currently developing a class in PHP that makes cURL requests and returns the answer as JSON for it to be processed by jQuery on my page. So far — no problems.
*(Note that the only way for me to load that content is by using my own server - I'm querying a website's API with my private API key)*

The problem is that some pages are slow (because of their server), and that plus the request to my server with jQuery makes it long to load a page, which makes around 5 seconds (or more) with no feedback at all for the user.

What I was wondering if there's any jQuery event for `$.ajax` which is called when the request is sent to the server (meaning that the server also started loading the requested page), but before the actual request to my page ended.

I'm trying to achieve this:

```
*user click* (0)
Sending request... (1)
Request sent. Loading page... (2)
Page loaded. (2)
```

- Event 0 would be just a click
- Event 1 would be jQuery's `$.ajax({ beforeSend: function(){} );`
- Event 2 is what I want. It'd be something like `onSend`, but sadly it doesn't exist
- Event 3 would be jQuery's `$.ajax({ complete: function(){ } });`

As a side note: I'm using jQuery, but I have no problems in using plain JavaScript if needed.

Comment: Have you checked the jQuery API? `.success()` ?

Comment: @ToddMotto `success` will be the same as `complete` but with regards to no errors in the response.

Comment: I assume you may simulate `onSend` event just putting the functionality right at the end of `beforeSend`, since what you are talking about is exactly between the end of `beforeSend` and start of `complete`.

Comment: The browser can't really tell anything about what the server is doing. It's fairly difficult to even know whether a request has made it off the client computer/device.

Comment: According to the docs it isn't. "Complete: A function to be called when the request finishes (after success and error callbacks are executed)"

Comment: @ToddMotto it happens at the same point in the life cycle as far as the OP is concerned: after the HTTP response has been received.

Comment: There is no such thing in AJAX – but if the connection from the client to your own server is not the bottleneck here, then I can’t see any real need for it … just displaying a standard activity indicator like one of those spinning GIFs should be enough to signal to the user that something is processed in the background, should it not? And five seconds aren’t the world for an action the user explicitly requested. Accompany it by an _explanation_ that it might take longer sometimes, that should be sufficient enough IMHO.

Comment: I am with @CBroe, a loading gif is what it is used in this cases. 5 seconds is not that much.

Comment: Otherwise, you will have to dive deeper into browser-specific extensions to the XMLHttpRequest object – f.e. Firefox offers a few additional events, like onloadstart, onprogress … https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIXMLHttpRequestEventTarget

Comment: In addition to web sockets, you could use polling. So you send your initial ajax request to a "launcher" script, which starts the long process and does not wait for it to complete before sending the response to the client. Then, the client can poll the server periodically, looking for the results of the long process. When the long process completes, it can write the results in something like session, a database, or a file. The poll script checks for that response and outputs it when it exists, otherwise it sends "0" (or something), indicating to the client to poll again.

Comment: Would the upload progress event help at all here, or does that only happen when there actually is a file to upload. If it would work, then you would be able to use it to tell when the "upload" is complete, which would mean the request has been completely received by the server.

Comment: Thanks to everyone, but 5 seconds are WAY too much for me. Why? Because my app loads at the start (like MEGA) and then it's super-fast (only javascript), and 5 seconds are damn much. And since it's a common action (the main action of my page), it's too much to wait for. However, I found the answer. Check out the code in my commentary under the best answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this can perform what you want:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 2) {
    alert("loading page");
  }
}
```

XMLHttpRequest has this states:
0: request not initialized 
1: server connection established
2: request received 
3: processing request 
4: request finished and response is ready

I don't know if this really works. I never had to use a differente state of 4.

Comment: +1. Unfortunately jQuery does not support this (they only fire a `sent` event for state `1`)

Comment: Unfortunately jQuery does not support this, because this is unnecessary.

Comment: It doesn't matter if jQuery "supports this" (I think you mean "implements"), because you can simply do it. You don't have to rely on jQuery for everything, javascript is always there too.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that not all ready states are accessible from all browsers

Comment: i really cannot understand the difference from doing this `alert("loading page")` on the `beforeSend` or on the `readyState == 2` someone can tell me??

Comment: @PauloRoberto `beforeSend` will show the alert right before sending the request, i.e. there's no request sent (yet). `readyState == 2` will send it as soon as the request is *started* processing by server, but hasn't finished yet.

Answer (score 2):

The Ajax have the default events that can be handled with here on the reference: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

But i'll do a sample to you see how it works.

The HTML code for a sample:

```
<input type=button id=yourButtonID name=yourButtonID>
```

-> **(0)** - The `onClick` event.

```
$("#yourButtonID").click(AjaxFunction());
```

-> (1), (2), (3) The `AjaxFunction`.

```js
function AjaxFunction(){

  $.ajax({
    url: "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
  }).beforeSend(function() {
    //show the ajax image
  }).done(function(data) {
    alert(data);
  }).fail(function() {
    alert("sorry, it failed");
  }).success(function() {
    alert("Sucess!");
  });
}
```

If you want to show to the user that the Request is happening, you just need to show to the user a ajax loading image on the `beforeSend` event, like that one:

[image: Ajax loading]

Something like `onSend` is the `beforeSend` because it executes before sending, and while are you sending, why you would fire a event?

Basically, ajax is a useful tool to make XHR's (XMLHTTPRequest's) that have pre-made events that you can use before you send the request, when your request is done, and if it fails, and if it success.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want two responses from server: the first as soon as it receives your request, and the second containing the payload from the other server.

Since a regular ajax HTTP request can only have one response, you could use web sockets instead.
This allows the server to 'push' data to the client.

see the links below:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/